# How to rename/recreate a table without disrupting service?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, locking

I've a table I need to purge without disrupting the service. About 99.99% of data should be deleted, so I'm trying to recreate the table and moving the 0.01% usefull data into the new table as following (and I will truncate the old table later) :

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
  LOCK TABLE table1 IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  /* I rename the old table */
  ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table1_to_be_deleted;
  /* And I recreate the table */
  CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ...
  );
  /* Restore usefull data from old table to new one */
  INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table1_to_be_deleted WHERE toBeKept = 1;
COMMIT;
```

But when I run my transaction I've got some client's error due to rows not found into the new table but present in the old one. These rows are well tagged as to be kept so they should be copied from old table to the new inside the transaction and found by the client's request....

When other requests are waiting for a lock acquired on a table, has it got a pointer to the targeted object? It's the only I've which can explained the update of the old table after I commit my transaction...

PS : I'm using Postgres 9.1

Comment: those rows are inserted after your commit?..

Answer (score 1):

To do that I'd rather:

1. create auxilary table
2. create rules to DML instead of original table to auxilary
3. create rule to select instead of original, `unionned' both
4. move good data from ONLY original to auxilary
5. truncate original
6. either move back data (will not need to rebuild references) or rename
7. drop obsoleted rules and objects

But really, I'd just delete from where 99%, not inventing the wheel